# Cannot navigate to specified url if using Ng build

Tags: routes, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have my **Angular 2** application . I am running on localhost . I have a page on **url :localhost:5050**. if I directly paste the url localhost:5050/test2 I get error on the browser page "**Cannot GET /test2**"
this is my route

```
        { path: '', component: Test1Component },
        { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component },
        { path: 'test3', component: test3lComponent},
```

I have no idea about the issue . I have to send a link(link contains the url of the application of a particular page https://xx.xx.xx.xx/test2) to customer. so the customer can navigate to the actual page from the link

Update:If I use **ng serve** and run on **localhost:4200/test2** it works(it routes) 
But if I use **ng build** and run on **localhost:5050/test2** I get **Cannot GET /test2** error

Below is my server.js

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
   Content-Type, Accept, X-Trace-Id, X-Egress-Time, X-Ingress-Time");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
next();
  });
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

Comment: What is going on in the Test2Component? 
Does localhost:5050/test2 work fine?
If so have you tried putting the test3lComponent in place of the Test2Component as a test?

Comment: The flow of the application is fine .I can route properly from test1 to test2 to test3 in a sequence . But when I directly want to navigate from browser to localhost:5050/test2 i get the error . The main task it to navigate to the any page from the url by specifying the direct path of the component

Comment: Ok i got you, what does the rest of your router file look like?

Comment: @BenjiLees  Below is my routes and my index is  <base href="/">

        const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: Test1Component},
    { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component },
    { path: 'Test3:id', component: Test3Component },
  
];

Comment: I am using node 

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Trace-Id, X-Egress-Time, X-Ingress-Time");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
});

Comment: have you read my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think its actually an issue with your server, you are currently sending a get request to your server which is attempting to match `localhost:5050/test2` which doesn't exist. If you alter the application so that all unknown routes return the basic application angular will handle the rest and re-route your application base on the url.

i.e in express something like:

```
  app.use('/*', express.static('./dist/index.html'));
```

Comment: I have read and tried few different way 
this is how it is in my node `app.use('*',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));`


I tried what you told me I am getting this error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: have you thought about using a proxy like `express-http-proxy` ?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue and followed the documentation on the link below.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

i am using Apache server and hence modified the rewire rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

i hope this helps..